# Perspective problem with a 3D bar-chart using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, 3d

I am currently building a 3D bar-chart using D3.js and basing that on the code available [here](https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/613d43d39372f99ae2dcea14f0f90617)

The problem I encounter is that, when putting all the bars close to each other and rotating my bar chart, the perspective/projection/view does something a bit weird and makes some values completely flat at some angles. Now I know that this is probably just a perspective issue but I would very much like to correct it.

Here is the code I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-3d/build/d3-3d.min.js"></script>
<body>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<style type="text/css">
button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
</style>
<button>update</button>
<script>
    var origin = [480, 300], scale = 20, j = 10, cubesData = [], alpha = 0, beta = 0, startAngle = Math.PI/6;
    var svg    = d3.select('svg').call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged).on('start', dragStart).on('end', dragEnd)).append('g');
    var color  = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
    var cubesGroup = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'cubes');
    var mx, my, mouseX, mouseY;

    var cubes3D = d3._3d()
        .shape('CUBE')
        .x(function(d){ return d.x; })
        .y(function(d){ return d.y; })
        .z(function(d){ return d.z; })
        .rotateY( startAngle)
        .rotateX(-startAngle)
        .origin(origin)
        .scale(scale);

    function processData(data, tt){

        /* --------- CUBES ---------*/

        var cubes = cubesGroup.selectAll('g.cube').data(data, function(d){ return d.id });

        var ce = cubes
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'cube')
            .attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.id); })
            .attr('stroke', function(d){ return d3.color(color(d.id)).darker(2); })
            .merge(cubes)
            .sort(cubes3D.sort);

        cubes.exit().remove();

        /* --------- FACES ---------*/

        var faces = cubes.merge(ce).selectAll('path.face').data(function(d){ return d.faces; }, function(d){ return d.face; });

        faces.enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('class', 'face')
            .attr('fill-opacity', 0.95)
            .classed('_3d', true)
            .merge(faces)
            .transition().duration(tt)
            .attr('d', cubes3D.draw);

        faces.exit().remove();

        /* --------- TEXT ---------*/

        var texts = cubes.merge(ce).selectAll('text.text').data(function(d){
            var _t = d.faces.filter(function(d){
                return d.face === 'top';
            });
            return [{height: d.height, centroid: _t[0].centroid}];
        });

        texts
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('class', 'text')
            .attr('dy', '-.7em')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
            .attr('font-weight', 'bolder')
            .attr('x', function(d){ return origin[0] + scale * d.centroid.x })
            .attr('y', function(d){ return origin[1] + scale * d.centroid.y })
            .classed('_3d', true)
            .merge(texts)
            .transition().duration(tt)
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .attr('stroke', 'none')
            .attr('x', function(d){ return origin[0] + scale * d.centroid.x })
            .attr('y', function(d){ return origin[1] + scale * d.centroid.y })
            .tween('text', function(d){
                var that = d3.select(this);
                var i = d3.interpolateNumber(+that.text(), Math.abs(d.height));
                return function(t){
                    that.text(i(t).toFixed(1));
                };
            });

        texts.exit().remove();

        /* --------- SORT TEXT & FACES ---------*/

        ce.selectAll('._3d').sort(d3._3d().sort);

    }

    function init(){
        cubesData = [];
        var cnt = 0;
        for(var z = -j/2; z <= j/2; z = z + 2){
            for(var x = -j; x <= j; x = x + 2){
            var h = d3.randomUniform(-2, -7)();
            var _cube = makeCube(h, x, z);
                _cube.id = 'cube_' + cnt++;
                _cube.height = h;
                cubesData.push(_cube);
            }
        }
        processData(cubes3D(cubesData), 1000);
    }

    function dragStart(){
        mx = d3.event.x;
        my = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragged(){
        mouseX = mouseX || 0;
        mouseY = mouseY || 0;
        beta   = (d3.event.x - mx + mouseX) * Math.PI / 230 ;
        alpha  = (d3.event.y - my + mouseY) * Math.PI / 230  * (-1);
        processData(cubes3D.rotateY(beta + startAngle).rotateX(alpha - startAngle)(cubesData), 0);
    }

    function dragEnd(){
        mouseX = d3.event.x - mx + mouseX;
        mouseY = d3.event.y - my + mouseY;
    }

    function makeCube(h, x, z){
        return [
            {x: x - 1, y: h, z: z + 1}, // FRONT TOP LEFT
            {x: x - 1, y: 0, z: z + 1}, // FRONT BOTTOM LEFT
            {x: x + 1, y: 0, z: z + 1}, // FRONT BOTTOM RIGHT
            {x: x + 1, y: h, z: z + 1}, // FRONT TOP RIGHT
            {x: x - 1, y: h, z: z - 1}, // BACK  TOP LEFT
            {x: x - 1, y: 0, z: z - 1}, // BACK  BOTTOM LEFT
            {x: x + 1, y: 0, z: z - 1}, // BACK  BOTTOM RIGHT
            {x: x + 1, y: h, z: z - 1}, // BACK  TOP RIGHT
        ];
    }

    d3.selectAll('button').on('click', init);

    init();
</script>
</body>
```

And here is an illustration of the problem with two images.

The first image does show my bar and its value clearly.[image: Highlighted bar is displayed]

Slightly rotating to get the second image however makes it "disappear" (I have however the impression however that it doesn't disappear but just got to a very small height value)[image: Highlighted bar is not visible]

Would anyone know where this is coming from?

Comment: it look like it is using a **parallel projection** and the sorting of shapes based on distance is causing this problem, I would suggest use Canvas with WebGL.

Comment: @rioV8 well I'm using d3 for everything else and I would like to keep using it as much as possible, especially since I don't know how easy this would be in webGL

Comment: it is just defining a set of openGL triangles the same as you do with the cube definition. You need a proper Z-buffer system and SVG does not have it

Comment: @rioV8 do you have a link to an example or an easy implementation of that for me to try right away?

Comment: Bare WebGL is a lot of work. I used ThreeJS https://i.imgur.com/DoGy23y.png No artifacts anymore and perspective camera

Comment: @rioV8 Seems pretty nice. Could you share the code?

Comment: @rioV8 I have been trying to get this to work with ThreeJS but I am somehow struggling with it. Would you mind sharing the code ?

Comment: @rioV8 do you get these notifications at all? Would be nice of you to share some code/explanations so that this question could be properly answered and not left open

Comment: I can see a lot of issues in both images. Are you sure that you have enabled the depth test and that you even have a depth buffer?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I am using D3 currently so not sure I can do that

Comment: @LBes Oh, I see. But it's a issue of the order of drawing. You have to draw the objects from the back to the front, so that the object which are nearer to the point of view cover the objects which are behind them. But I don't know how to achieve this in *D3*.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That's not possible with D3, that's why I was told to do it with ThreeJS. But I don't know how to get started with it. Would you have an example

Comment: Not replying to your question but important: 3d charts are a bad practice in the industry (source: research / Google). You may really want to consider using another type of chart. The many bars in the screenshots are not easy to read / interpret at all.

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I know they are not and that's not the purpose of this. It's a simple example that I am trying to get. I want 3D for a totally different purpose and 3D is sometimes useful, especially when your data is originally 3D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it thanks to comments from @rioV8 who suggested that SVG was not adequate here.

I therefore used `Three.js`. Here is my function makeCube

```
function makeCube(h, x, length_x, z, length_z){


            h = normalise_height(h)
            h = -h //for drawing purposes

            x = x
            z = z


            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(length_x, h, length_z);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00ff, wireframe: false } );
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);


            var eGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            var positions = [];
            positions.push([0, 0, 0]);
            positions.push([length_x, 0, 0]);
            positions.push([length_x, 0, length_z]);
            positions.push([0, 0, length_z]);
            positions.push([0, 0, 0]);
            positions.push([0, h, 0]);
            positions.push([length_x, h, 0]);
            positions.push([length_x, h, length_z]);
            positions.push([0, h, length_z]);
            positions.push([0, h, 0]);
            positions.push([0, h, length_z]);
            positions.push([0, 0, length_z]);
            positions.push([0, h, length_z]);
            positions.push([length_x, h, length_z]);
            positions.push([length_x, 0, length_z]);
            positions.push([length_x, h, length_z]);

            positions.push([length_x, h, 0]);
            positions.push([length_x, 0, 0]);

            for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++)
            {
                //console.log(positions[i])
                eGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(positions[i][0]-length_x/2.0,
                                                          positions[i][1]-h/2.0,
                                                          positions[i][2]-length_z/2.0));
            }

            length_x -= epsilon;
            length_z -= epsilon;

            var eMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000000, linewidth: 1 } );
            var edges = new THREE.Line( eGeometry , eMaterial );
            mesh.add( edges );

            mesh.position.set(x+length_x/2.0, h/2.0, z+length_z/2.0);
            parentObject.add(mesh);

            return mesh;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please look at this question regarding d3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312494/convert-2d-shape-into-3d-in-d3-js-and-adjust-height-according-to-the-value-in-an

Answer (score 1):

d3-3d is using wrong coordinates for sorting cubes. Putting bottom face centroid into sort function will fix it.

```
cubes3D.sort = function(a, b){
    var _a = a.faces[5].centroid.z, _b = b.faces[5].centroid.z;
    return _a < _b ? -1 : _a > _b ? 1 : _a >= _b ? 0 : NaN;
};
```